# Convert Movie to OpenNI *.oni video

Tags: c++, c, kinect, video-processing, openni

The [Kinect OpenNI library](http://openni.org/) uses a custom video file format to store videos that contain rgb+d information. These videos have the extension *.oni. I am unable to find any information or documentation whatsoever on the ONI video format.

I'm looking for a way to convert a conventional rgb video to a *.oni video. The depth channel can be left blank (ie zeroed out). For example purposes, I have a MPEG-4 encoded .mov file with audio and video channels.

There are no restrictions on how this conversion must be made, I just need to convert it somehow! Ie, imagemagick, ffmpeg, mencoder are all ok, as is custom conversion code in C/C++ etc.

So far, all I can find is [one C++ conversion utility in the OpenNI sources](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiConvertXToONI/NiConvertXToONI.cpp). From the looks of it, I this converts from one *.oni file to another though. I've also managed to find [a C++ script by a phd student that converts images from a academic database into a *.oni file](http://www.uco.es/dptos/aceyte/arquitectura/profesores/jcgamez/?RESEARCH_%28English%29). Unfortunately the code is in spanish, not one of my native languages.

Any help or pointers much appreciated!

EDIT: As my usecase is a little odd, some explanation may be in order. The OpenNI Drivers (in my case I'm using the excellent [Kinect for Matlab library](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30242-kinect-matlab)) allow you to specify a *.oni file when creating the Kinect context. This allows you to emulate having a real Kinect attached that is receiving video data - useful when you're testing / developing code (you don't need to have the Kinect attached to do this). In my particular case, we will be using a Kinect in the production environment (process control in a factory environment), but during development all I have is a video file :) Hence wanting to convert to a *.oni file. We aren't using the Depth channel at the moment, hence not caring about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer for you, but take a look at the NiRecordRaw and NiRecordSynthetic examples in OpenNI/Samples.  They demonstrate how to create an ONI with arbitrary or modified data.  See how MockDepthGenerator is used in NiRecordSynthetic -- in your case you will need MockImageGenerator.
For more details you may want to ask in the openni-dev google group.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into this command and its associated documentation

**NiConvertXToONI** --
NiConvertXToONI opens any recording, takes every node within it, and records it to a new ONI recording. It receives both the input file and the output file from the command line.