# OpenNI file format (ONI)

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

I need to generate my own ONI files, science depth images in my project are not generated using regular devices such as Kinect.

I checked their github and found out that there are two libraries https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2
and 
https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.

1- Should I assume that OpenNI2 is the newer version and recommended to be used?

2- As mentioned here "[Convert Movie to OpenNI *.oni video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242885/convert-movie-to-openni-oni-video)", in openNI, it is possible to write ONI files, however it seems that this functionality has been removed from the newer version. Is it true?

3- Can VideoWriter (openCV) write ONI files? help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) You can find documentation about OpenNI on their [website](http://structure.io/openni). OpenNI2 is newer, but OpenNI is still available since code written for OpenNI is not compatible with OpenNI2.

2) In OpenNI2 you can use the Recorder class to write ONI files. Please refer to the [NiRecordSynthetic-Sample](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiRecordSynthetic/NiRecordSynthetic.cpp).

3) Probably not out of the box. It uses FFMPEG to encode the video so you would need the appropriate codec.

Comment: OpenNI website is down